# Get relationship attributes with Django's REST API

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

There are two tables `user, phone` which are linked by an intermediate table `owner`.  Here the goal is to use Rest API to get all phones from a specific user, 
`http://127.0.0.1/users/alice/phones/`.

I use `ModelSerializer` as  serializer and `ViewSet` as view. Please let me know how to get this done? I have no idea how to route `/users/user_name/phones/` to get phones from a specific user.
Thanks.

Code snippet:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=User

class PhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Phone

class OwnerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Owner
        depth=1

// views
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset=User.objects.all()
    serializer_class=UserSerializer


class PhoneViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset=Phone.objects.all()
    serializer_class=PhoneSerializer

....
```

Comment: Is it important to use this url: `/users/user_name/phones/` or you may use this one `/phones/?user=user_name` ?

Comment: /users/user_name/phones/  and /phones/?user=user_name will both be okay.  The former is more like Rest style though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to create a [filter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/).

It will be something like this:

1) Create filter (Make sure that [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) is installed.):

```
# filters.py
import django_filters


class PhoneFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    user = django_filters.Filter(name="user__user_name")

    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        fields = ('user',)
```

2) Add filter to your *ViewSet*:

```
# views.py
class PhoneViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset=Phone.objects.all()
    serializer_class=PhoneSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = filters.PhoneFilter
```

And now you may use this url: `/phones/?user=user_name`.

Comment: Thanks. How to use /user/user_name/phones to phones from the user? Django official states: "If you have ad-hoc methods that you need to be routed to, you can mark them as requiring routing using the detail_route or list_route decorators.

The detail_route decorator contains pk in its URL pattern and is intended for methods which require a single instance. The list_route decorator is intended for methods which operate on a list of objects."

Answer (score 0):

Use `@detail_route` to route URL to your function, e.g.,

```
 @detail_route(methods=['get'])
 def phones(self, request, pk=None):
    pass
```

`http://127.0.0.1/users/alice/phones`  will work!